# XSLT how to add an attribute into an existing template without changing it

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to customise an existing XSLT template by adding a default attribute value if it is missing. The original template is from 3rd party and better not to be touched. Below is the code to illustrate what I want to achieve. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**The sample xml file to be transformed:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<images>
   <image href="https://cityyearnh.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/boat.jpg" width="300" />
   <image href="https://cityyearnh.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/boat.jpg"/>
</images>
```

Please note, there are 2 images in the xml file, one with @width attribute and one without. When @width is not defined, the XLST file below will not add a width attribute in the output html file.

**The existing XSLT file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html><body>
       <h2>My Images</h2>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="images/image" />
    </body></html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="img_template" match="images/image">
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <img>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@href|@width" />
    </img>
    <br />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/images/image/@href">
    <xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/images/image/@width">
    <xsl:attribute name="width"><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

When @width is not defined, I want to add a width attribute of 50% in the output html file. I could modify the original img_template to achieve what I want, for example,

```
<xsl:template name="img_template" match="images/image">
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <img>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@href" />
       <xsl:if test="@width">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@width" />
       </xsl:if>
       <xsl:if test="not(@width)">
          <xsl:attribute name="width">50%</xsl:attribute>
       </xsl:if>
    </img>
    <br />
</xsl:template>
```

However, it's not a good idea to modify the original template. Is there a way to call the original template and add some additional processing ?

I have tried to add an overriding template that calls the original and somehow add the default width attribute (but I do not know how). My code so far:

```
 <xsl:template match="images/image">
    <xsl:if test="@width">
       <xsl:call-template name="img_template" />
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="not(@width)">
       <p>Below image has no width attribute set. Add 50% width somehow ?</p>
       <xsl:call-template name="img_template" />
    </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
```

Any help/suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [@MichaelKey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/415448/michael-kay)'s suggestion, I have worked out the following solution:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:include href="original.xsl" />

<xsl:template match="images/image[not(@width)]">
    <xsl:variable name="old_content">
        <xsl:call-template name="img_template" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:call-template name="re-generate">
        <xsl:with-param name="oldcontent" select="$old_content"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="re-generate">
    <xsl:param name="oldcontent" />
    <img width="50%">
       <xsl:copy-of select="$oldcontent/img/@*" />
    </img>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$oldcontent/*[not(self::img)]" />
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the above, I have assumed that the original template is in file original.xsl. Also, the first node generated by img_template is assumed to be the img. For more complex processing, it would be ideal to pass to a java function.

Answer (score 1):

> it's not a good idea to modify the original template.

Why not? I would rewrite your stylesheet as:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/images">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>My Images</h2>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="image" />
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="image">
    <img src="{@href}" width="50%">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@width" />
    </img>
    <br/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@width">
    <xsl:attribute name="width">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This assigns a `width` attribute with a default value of 50% to *every* image. If the image does have its own `width` attribute, it will be used t overwrite the default value.

---

Alternatively, you could do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/images">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>My Images</h2>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="image" />
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="image">
    <img src="{@href}">
        <xsl:attribute name="width">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@width">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@width" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>50%</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </img>
    <br/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which is perhaps more verbose, but very clear.

---

### Added:

> Unfortunately, the original XSLT file is complex and comes as part of
>   a software package. We do not suppose to modify any files there for
>   maintenance reasons. Are there any ways to achieve what I want by
>   using "overrides" ?

Yes, you could add the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="image[not(@width)]" priority="1">
    <img src="{@href}" width="50%"/>
    <br/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi, Michael, thanks for the answer and the suggested xslt file which certainly looks much neat than my sample files. Unfortunately, the original XSLT file is complex and comes as part of a software package. We do not suppose to modify any files there for maintenance reasons. Are there any ways to achieve what I want by using "overrides" ?

Comment: @user3368148 See the addition to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It certainly works for this simple example. Unfortunately, it may not solve my problem in the way that this override solution repeats the original code (for example, <img src="@href">). The original template I am trying to customize is complex and has more than 100 lines of code. If I am going to override and repeat all codes, I still have a maintenance problem when the original is updated. The solution I am hoping to have is to use all the original codes, but add an attribute if it is missing without duplicating codes.

Comment: Of course, I appreciate very much your answers through which I learnt a lot more additional things.

Comment: @user3368148 The only way to add an attribute to an element is in a template matching that element. If you don't want to modify the existing template handling the element, you must add an overriding template. There is no way around this.

Comment: The template code I am working on is actually here :
https://github.com/dita-ot/dita-ot/blob/develop/src/main/plugins/org.dita.xhtml/xsl/xslhtml/dita2htmlImpl.xsl
The code concerning me is at line 1542 where <img> has no default width attribute. I want to add a default width="%50" without changing the original file, if possible.

Comment: I am afraid I have nothing to add.

Answer (score 1):

I've been dealing with a similar case recently where I was invoking a library stylesheet that put its output in a namespace, and I wanted it in no namespace. It would have meant overriding a lot of code. So instead I captured the output of the existing stylesheet in a variable, and transformed it.

Something like:

```
<xsl:template match="image">
  <xsl:variable name="temp">
    <xsl:apply-imports/>
  </xsl:variable>
  .. now process $temp e.g. to add missing attributes
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Greate idea! I will certainly try that way.